# Count registro entre multiples columnas

Tags: mysql

Buenos días / Buenas tardes. Mi duda es la siguiente. Tengo una tabla que tiene 12 columnas que son todas de distintas acciones, pero que cada una de esas acciones se puede calificar como EE, EC, OM. Lo que necesito es poder contar cuantas EE hay entre esas doce columnas. Como un contar.si de excel. ¿Existe la posibilidad de hacerlo sin hacer un count columna por columna? Encontré una forma de realizarlo pero por procedimiento que lamentable no me sirve ya que la consulta resultante la tengo que insertar en una variable de un highchart para que me genere un grafico.
Agradezco la ayuda. Muchas gracias.

[image: Ejemplo:]

Comment: Para que quede claro la pregunta, siempre es útil incluir ejemplos concretos de los datos y del resultado deseado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso es mas util un SUM con IF, que es parecido al CONTAR.SI:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ( IF(col01='EE',1,0) + IF(col02='EE',1,0) + .... ) as sum_cnt_ee  
FROM table1
```

Esto solo si la cuenta es por cada fila (cuantas EE hay en cada fila)
Si deseas contarlas en un grupo de filas agrupadas, se tendria que aplicar SUM al resultado anterior:

```
SELECT field1, field2, SUM( IF(col01='EE',1,0) + IF(col02='EE',1,0) + .... ) as cnt_ee  
FROM table1 
GROUP BY field1, field2
```

Si interesa solo obtener el total de EE's no habria necesidad de agrupar:

```
SELECT SUM( IF(col01='EE',1,0) + IF(col02='EE',1,0) + .... ) as cnt_total_ee  
FROM table1 
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Hey me sirvio, muchisimas gracias.